# PyPDF2 - issue with getFromTextFields

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to use PyPDF2 to extract "input/table" values from a PDF file.

The document is not flattened.
The first page of the document has a unique table.
The following pages have similar tables.

The extraction works well for the first and last page. However all pages in-between are missing.

My questions are:

1) Could the problem be related to the "names" in the tables being the same and it therefore overwrites the values over and over(see output example below)? How could this be solved?

```
'Groove_clearance_2[0]': '0.30',
 'Coating_thickness_2[0]': '8.4',
 'Coating_thickness_3[0]': '8.1',
 'Groove_clearance_3[0]': '0.40',
 'Groove_clearance_4[0]': '0.500',
 'Coating_thickness_4[0]': '7.0',
 'Coating_thickness_5[0]': None,
 'Groove_clearance_5[0]': None,
 'Additional_Comments[0]': 'schedule for overhauling the piston',
 'Ring_5[0]': None,
 'Ring_4[0]': 'Sharp edges ',
 'Ring_3[0]': 'Sharp edges',
 'Ring_2[0]': 'Sharp edges,lost tension,carbon on surface',
 'Ring_1[0]': 'Sharp edges',
 'Running_hours_7[0]': '2840',
 'Running_hours_6[0]': '48486',
 'Running_hours_5[0]': '34485',
 'Running_hours_4[0]': '34485',
 'Running_hours_3[0]': '23469',
 'Running_hours_2[0]': '23469',
```

2) I have tried to split the PDF into separate single page PDFs, but then no data can be extracted at all. It seems it then can't find any formFields. Any solution to this if 1) cannot be solved?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Tim

Comment: Hard to tell anything without a code sample and the PDF file.